# what does ''loving shows like one's slip showing'' mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms

So, I'm translating The Sea, The Sea and there is this sentence which I do not understand. It goes like this: She is quite right, loving shows like slip showing, as I once said to her when her slip was showing!

What does this mean? Thank you! :)

Comment: [slip (clothing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_%28clothing%29)   Also see: ["your slip is showing"](https://www.bing.com/search?q=your+slip+is+showing+saying&pc=MOZI&form=MOZTSB)

Comment: Don't know why this was flagged - it seems like a reasonable question. If a lady's slip was showing, (in the old days - when we wore our underwear strictly *under*) presumably, she would be unaware of the fact that she was embarrassing herself... Like being in love, when you act like an idiot and don't realize it.